# iOS: Not receiving the write requests from Central to Peripheral

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

I am trying to get the write request sent from Central and no delegate is getting called for the same in Peripheral. If I unsubscribe characteristic from Central then didUnsubscribeFromCharacteristic gets called. I am not sure how will I get the request in Peripheral application.

#### Central code:

> [peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];

Tried calling same method with type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse, its not working as expected.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you init your characteristics in the peripheral? Check their properties, you need:

```
properties: CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite
permissions: CBAttributePermissionWriteable
```

Which of the PeripheralManager Delegate methods get called?
Must be more than just peripheralManager:central:didUnsubscribeFromCharacteristic

```
peripheralManagerDidUpdateState
peripheralManager:didAddService:error
peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising:error
...
```

See the CBPeripheralManagerDelegate....
Check if all of them get called and the errors. Maybe something is wrong with your services/characteristics...

And check, if methods in your central get called, too. E.g.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service
             error:(NSError *)error
```

And, of course, you have to init your peripheralManager in your peripheral with the correct delegate (and implement all other needed delegate methods):

```
self.peripheralManager  = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in Peripheral you should call `didReceiveWriteRequests` delegate.